# Why is the parameter of then() handler function wrapped in curly braces in this POST request?

Tags: javascript

So, here's the whole request:

```html
fetch(`/api/quotes?quote=${quote}&person=${person}`, {
    method: 'POST',
  })
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(({quote}) => {
    const newQuote = document.createElement('div');
    newQuote.innerHTML = `
    <h3>Congrats, your quote was added!</h3>
    <div class="quote-text">${quote.quote}</div>
    <div class="attribution">- ${quote.person}</div>
    <p>Go to the <a href="index.html">home page</a> to request and view all quotes.</p>
    `
    newQuoteContainer.appendChild(newQuote);
  });
```

And this is the line I can't figure out

```
.then(({quote}) => {
```

Why curly braces around "quote" parameter? How does this work?
The response body for this request looks like this:

```
{
  quote: {
            id: number,
            quote: 'some string',
            person: 'some string'
         }
 }
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Assigning_to_new_variable_names

Comment: Hey Marcin, on the second step of then() you have parsed the body of the response as Json. so the next you have to do is just to get it as `then(result) => { console.log(result.quote.id); }`. I have not seen anything like ({quote}). check it and let me know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your response is an object with an atribute `quote`. `{ quote }` will get that object and assign to `quote` the content of the property `quote`.

See this example:

```js
let foo = {
  bar: 5
}

function printbar({bar}) {
  console.log(bar)
}

printbar(foo)
```

This is called "object destructuring". Check this post for an in depth explanation: https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/05/es6-in-depth-destructuring/